# File permissions while installing a python module

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, software-installation, python

I would like to install `sphinx-doc` from the sources so I `git clone` the module then installed it with `sudo python setup.py install`.

```
Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2016.4-py2.7.egg
Searching for MarkupSafe==0.23
Best match: MarkupSafe 0.23
Removing MarkupSafe 0.18 from easy-install.pth file
Adding MarkupSafe 0.23 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Finished processing dependencies for Sphinx==1.4b1.dev-20160423
```

Then I realized that I don't have the permissions to use it:

```
$ sphinx-quickstart
bash: /usr/local/bin/sphinx-quickstart: Permission denied
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/sphinx-quickstart 
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 357 Apr 23 16:56 /usr/local/bin/sphinx-quickstart
```

The question is, how to install it with the correct permissions?

I often have this kind of issues when I have to use `sudo` to create a folder or to mount a drive to /media. This is a bit off topic, but `/media` is `755` and as a regular user I cannot mount my own drives on my own computer without being `root`. 
Is that normal?

Comment: Why aren't you using your distribution's binary package?

Comment: Because I would like to develop on it `python setup.py develop`

Comment: Oh. Don't build *or* install local packages as root. Bad things can happen. Do everything as user.

Comment: I guess it's good advice :)

Comment: why mess up your system with locally compiled versions of stuff that's already packaged for ubuntu (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/installing-debian.html)?  This is an ugly hack that only a programmer could love.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to install Python packages from source, you should do so in a virtualenv. That way you minimize the chance that you break your system's python, and it you make it possible to just remove the installed package without fear of removing too much.

In order to do so you must first install virtualenv, e.g. using

```
 sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

after that is installed create a virtualenv somewhere and activate it:

```
 sudo mkdir /opt/util
 sudo chown $USER /opt/util
 virtualenv /opt/util/sphinx-doc
 source /opt/util/sphinx-doc/bin/activate
```

after that run your

```
 python setup.py install
```

in the `git` cloned directory, you should not have to use `sudo`.

As long as the virtualenv is active you should be able to run `sphinx-doc` or any (other) utilites the `python setup.py install` creates. You can also run those when the virtualenv is not active by using `/opt/util/sphinx-doc/bin/<UTILNAME>` (for which you might want to make an alias).

`/opt/util/sphinx-doc` can be changed to whatever you want. But if you put such virtualenvs next to each other, you can easily create some script for automatic updating of any `pip` installed packages, for defining aliases etc.